# using json object data in jquery select

Tags: php, json, jquery

```
{"names": [
    {"patientName": "Ratna"},
    {"patientName": "raju" },
    {"patientName": "krishna"},
    {"patientName": "kishore"},
    {"patientName": "Kishore1"},
    {"patientName": "mahesh"}
]}
```

this is the JSON object i'm getting from Ajax call
so now i want to add all `patientName` values to select box through jquery

can any one tell me how to accomplish this ??

here i'm using $.ajax() function for ajax call

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var select = $('#selectid');
$.each(data.names, function(i, v){
    select.append('<option value="'+v.patientName+'">'+v.patientName+'</option>');
}
```

Doc - [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/FkKhQ/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
var selectbox = '';
var options = '';

for (var i = 0; i < YourJsonObject.names.length; i++) {
options += '<option value="' + YourJsonObject.names[i] + '">' + YourJsonObject.names[i] + '</option>';
}

$("select#yourSelectBoxID").html(selectbox);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var data = {
    "names": [
        {"patientName": "Ratna"},
        {"patientName": "raju" },
        {"patientName": "krishna"},
        {"patientName": "kishore"},
        {"patientName": "Kishore1"},
        {"patientName": "mahesh"}
    ]
}
var names = data.names;
var options = [];
for(i=0,len=data.names.length;i<len;i++){
    options[i] = '<option>' + names[i].patientName + '</option>';
}
$('<select></select>').append(options.join('')).appendTo('body');
```